# SignalR: Any built-in capability to prevent Clients from calling server function frequently?

Tags: security, signalr, signalr-hub

Is there any capability in signalR to prevent malicious users from calling server functions frequently, by changing client side scripts.

for example, restriction for functions: three calls per second from a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SignalR does not have anything like that out of the box, you would have to implement your throttling logic in your code.

If you then configure CORS properly, *normal* (*) malicious users should not be able to modify your script or access your hubs from unauthorized domains, so these 2 things together should allow you to reach your goal. But you have to implement it yourself.

(*) super hackers might be able to find a way if they really want to.

Comment: I think this doesn't need a super hacker. anyone can easily change client-side scripts and put the 'send()' function within a for loop! The solution should be using some server-side time stamp to make user to run functions in some predefined periods.

Comment: Well, *anyone* means a decently smart programmer at least. And if it was so easy, the web would be broken already, no? How difficult might be to take whatever script downloaded from any site and transform it in a DDOS system? It's just a loop and Ajax requests no? Is the web that weak? Did you ever see any JS framework around, like jQuery or Angular or whatever, support what you ask for out of the box? It would be the same issue, no? Such solution are usually outside of such libraries, it's more logic you can always build on top of those.

Comment: Yes, you are right. i was looking for a solution to reduce the server overload, BTW. i will implement the time stamp table by my own. Thank you a lot. Your book was great for me for learning SignalR. it really deserves to be named as a cook book!

Comment: Thanks :) And BTW with the, probably eccessive, "super hacker" definition I was referring to breaking CORS than building some brute force system, which of course is not so hard but it could be done for everything, starting from basic HTTP requests first.